# Неправильно фильтруются записи INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Формирую суммарный отчет по часам работ и простоев строительных машин на объектах. Пользователь вносит в форму на сайте для одного наименования машины информацию о том сколько машина работала и стояла в определенный день с указанием причин простоев. Информация с формы заносится в таблицы `jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain`,`HoursRaboty`(чтобы не громоздить все в одной таблице) ,а причины простоев и часы простоя с этой же формы в таблицу `jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond` из-за того, что у одной машины может быть несколько причин простоев.

Схема БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что в таблице `jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond` во внешних ключах `Prostoy` и `id_fk` есть повторяющиеся значения и `INNER JOIN` работает некорректно(происходит дублирование строк, которые удалось исключить в начальном `SELECT` оператором `DISTINCT`). В итоговом отчете(ссылка на sql fiddle внизу) ошибка в сумме часов в колонках `Простои` и `Причины простоев`. Вместо 12 часов для камаза выводит 10 и причины простоев по отдельности тоже дают в сумме 10(кстати группировку по причинам корректно не получается сделать из-за двух внешних ключей, тоже нужна помощь). Почему-то исключается строка в таблице `jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond` под `id = 70`

Запрос:

```
SELECT avto.Marka AS Марка, SUM(DISTINCT HR.otrab) as 'Часы работы ',SUM(sec.Hours1) as Простои,CONVERT(group_concat(DISTINCT concat(prostoy.Prichina,'=',sec.Hours1) separator ';') USING 'utf8') as 'Причины простоев',CONVERT(group_concat(DISTINCT concat(HR.VipolnennayaRabota,'=',HR.v_rab) separator ';') USING 'utf8') as 'Выполненные работы'
FROM
jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain main
INNER JOIN avto ON main.Marka=avto.ID_Avto
INNER JOIN (
SELECT  VipolnennayaRabota, SUM(V_raboty) as v_rab,SUM(OtrabotanoMachine_hours) as otrab,id_main
    FROM HoursRaboty 
    GROUP BY VipolnennayaRabota) HR ON HR.id_main=main.id
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Prostoy,SUM(Hours)as Hours1,id_fk
   FROM jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond
   GROUP BY id_fk,Prostoy)sec ON  main.id = sec.id_fk 
   INNER JOIN prostoy on sec.Prostoy = prostoy.ID_Prosyoy
   GROUP BY  avto.Marka
```

Для тестирования [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67984/1)

Очень нужна помощь уже голову сломал, не могу сделать неделю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` работает именно так, как и *должен*. Он обязан дублировать строки потому как к каждой из записей таблицы A, он должен взять каждую из записей таблицы B. При этом, если в одной из таблиц не найдется записей для склейки он *должен* вообще не выдавать строку (из за этого у вас проблема с id=70, потому как из за ошибки в группировке выполненных работ (вы id_main не включили в group by) у вас в работах просто нет записи для одной из машин).

Для того что бы `JOIN` выдавал записи, даже если подходящих нет во второй таблице следует использовать `LEFT JOIN`.

Что бы записи не перемножались надо подать `JOIN` ровно по одной записи для условий объединения, т.е. их надо догруппировать до нужного уровня заранее. В принципе можно что бы в одной из таблиц было несколько строк, но тогда придется правильно расставлять `sum` и `max`, в зависимости от того много записей в конкретной таблице или одна.

А ваш запрос должен выглядеть [например так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67984/3) (я еще взял на себя смелость поменять расчет v_rab, а то вы почему то по видам работ брали одно поле, а для общей суммы использовали сумму чего то подозрительно смахивающего на ID видов работ):

```
SELECT avto.marka as Марка,v.otrab as 'Часы работы',s.hours as Простои,
       s.g_hours as 'Причины простоев',v.v_rab as 'Выполненные работы'
  FROM avto
  LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT marka,CONVERT(group_concat(concat(VipolnennayaRabota,'=',otrab) separator ';') USING 'utf8') v_rab,SUM(otrab) as otrab
     FROM (
      SELECT marka,VipolnennayaRabota, SUM(V_raboty) as v_rab,
             SUM(OtrabotanoMachine_hours) as otrab
        FROM HoursRaboty h,jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain m
       WHERE h.id_main=m.id
       GROUP BY marka,VipolnennayaRabota
     ) V
   GROUP BY marka
  ) v ON v.marka=avto.id_avto
  LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT marka,sum(s.Hours) hours,
          CONVERT(group_concat(concat(p.Prichina,'=',s.Hours) separator ';') USING 'utf8') g_hours
     FROM (
       SELECT marka,Prostoy,SUM(Hours) as Hours
         FROM jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond s, jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain m
        WHERE s.id_fk=m.id
        GROUP BY marka,Prostoy
     ) s, prostoy p
    WHERE s.Prostoy = p.ID_Prosyoy
    GROUP BY marka
  ) s ON s.marka=avto.id_avto
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, что  ввел в заблуждение с колонкой `Выполненные работы` в ней считаются не часы работ, а сумма объема работ в разных ед.измерения за сумму  часов смен. Была проблема только в `простоях` и `причины простоев`. Я сократил отчет почти до минимума из-за этого стало нелогично, а сам отчет состоит из 14 столбцов. Запрос немного изменил под свою задачу, все работает, огромное спасибо за помощь и подробное объяснение. Left join плохо понимаю, пытался обойтись без него.

Comment: @Vitaly В данном случае left может и не особо нужен, скорее перестраховка. Его функционал необходим если по какой то марке будет наработка, но не будет простоя. или наоборот простой без наработки. Обычный join в этом случае всю запись не покажет